# How do I do a svndumpfilter when my project name is multiple words?

Tags: linux, subversion

I have a full back up of my large repo that I'm trying to break up into smaller repos based on project.  I have a few projects with spaces in the name, ie "My Project". How do I do `svndumpfilter` to create a dump for only `My Project.dump`?

This is what I'm using:

```
cat /svn_backup/name of latest full backup file e.g. full_20190629-1700h01 | svndumpfilter include name of project e.g. My Project > name of project.dump
```

Comment: Don't know if it works, but have you tried putting the project name in quotes like `zcat /svn_backup/full_20190629-1700h01.gz | svndumpfilter include "My Project" > "My Project.dump"`? If your backup is gzipped, you probably want to use `zcat` instead of `cat`.

Comment: @Freddy I did try that and it gave me "Invalid copy source path '/Project'.  And I also unzipped the back up so I will change that in my question.

Comment: "project" is entity, which **doesn't exist** and even **doesn't have sense** in terms of *repository* of "this specific tool - svndumpfilter". Even worse - none of obects in URLs of Linux-FS can have spaces "as is" in names. Period. Define **for yourself**, what you want (in commonly used and accepted terms), re-phrase your question